SetActive for multiple cameras
I have a working script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Interactive_map : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public Camera[] cameras;
    
    void Start()
    {
        cameras[0].GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;                
    }
    
    public void TriggerClicked(int cam)
    {        
        for (int i = 0; i < cameras.Length; i++)
        {
            cameras[i].GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
        }

        cameras[cam].GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;          
    }
}

But I need to disable and enable cameras entirely through SetActive() method. How can I do that correctly? Changing GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true; to SetActive(True) causes a mistake

Assets\Scripts\Interactive_map.cs(13,20): error CS1061: 'Camera' does
not contain a definition for 'SetActive' and no accessible extension
method 'SetActive' accepting a first argument of type 'Camera' could
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)


why using setactive? whats wrong with enable? this makes it sound like schoolwork..

well Camera indeed doesn't know SetActive ... GameObject does ...

As @derHugo hinted at in their comment, SetActive(bool) is a GameObject method, not a Component method (the Camera class is a child of Component, so it inherits all Component's properties, including enabled).
Therefore, you have to modify the Camera's GameObject through the .gameObject property, rather than changing the Camera directly:
cameras[i].GetComponent<Camera>().gameObject.SetActive(false);


As a side note, because your cameras array is already of type Camera, you don't need to use GetComponent<Camera>() on it. The call does nothing but make the enable/disable sequence ever so slightly slower:
cameras[i].enabled = false;
// or
cameras[i].gameObject.SetActive(false);

